# Form value posted null to controller with jquery post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, post

In an Asp.NET MVC project, I have a form in my cshtml page. I want to send form values to a controller with a jquery post adapter. I am using .serilize() function in order to get the form values and when I alert the serialized values I can get them as a string, however, when I send it to the controller it posts as null. Here is my cshtml page:

EditPage.cshtml

```
@model Models.PROJECTS

@using (Html.BeginForm(null,null,FormMethod.Post,new {id="EditForm"}))
{
    @*Html.AntiForgeryToken()*@

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PROJE_NO)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PROJECTNAME, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PROJECTNAME, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PROJECTNAME, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PROJECTCODE, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PROJECTCODE, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PROJECTCODE, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        .
        .
        .



        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <i class="fa fa-save fa-lg" id="saveBtn" style="cursor:pointer;color:green" title="Edit Project"></i>&nbsp;

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     }
    @section scripts
     {

    <script language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {


            $(document).on("click", "#saveBtn", function () {


                var formData = $('#EditForm').serialize();

                alert(JSON.stringify(formData));

                $.post('@Url.Action("EditProject", "Home")',
                    {
                        project: JSON.stringify(formData)

                    }).done(function(data) {

                    if (data.success) {

                        alertify.success(data.message);

                    } else {

                        alertify.error(data.message);
                    }
                }).fail(function() {
                    alertify.error('Error while editing project');
                });

            });
        });
   </script>
```

Here is the HomeController:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditProject(PROJECTS project)
        {

            try
            {
                using (dbContext = new ProjectsDbContext())
                {
                    dbContext.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    dbContext.SaveChanges();
                    return Json(new { success = true, message = "Project Info is Updated" });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Json(new { success = false, message = "Project Info Cannot be Updated" });
            }
        }
```

To the EditProject action, the parameter project comes as null. I don't know where I am doing wrong.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it's not because ``proje``in ``proje: JSON.stringify(formData)``, i think should be ``project: JSON.stringify(formData)``

Comment: @Sajid thank you very much for your help. It is actually the same in the project. Sorry about the typo. When I write it here I mistakenly write it as "proje"

Comment: you're welcome, so it's always null after update?

Comment: It is posted null to the action. I defined form's action as null, however it actually seems like going to another action. I also try to use .preventDefault(); method it also did not work.

Comment: can you add to the question the result of ``alert(JSON.stringify(formData));`` and ``PROJECTS`` class, i want to try this.

Comment: here is the result of the alert: "PROJE_NO=3&PROJECTNAME=something%20Project&PROJECTCODE=24" and here is the PROJECTS class 
 public partial class PROJECTS
    {
     
    
        public decimal PROJE_NO { get; set; }
        public string PROJECTNAME { get; set; }
        public string PROJECTCODE { get; set; }
      }

Comment: Actually the class 17 properties and the alert prints the same number of fields.

Comment: So the ``.post`` send data like ``FormData`` not like a ``json``. the solution is to delete``JSON.stringify`` and change ``project`` to: ``formData``. let me know if it's work for you i can add it like an answer.

Comment: var formData = $('#EditForm').serialize(); 
$.post('@Url.Action("EditProject", "Home")',
                    {
                        project: formData

                    }), and in controller:
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult EditProject(PROJECTS project)
 {}

this did not work also.

Comment: @Sajid I actually did not understand to change project to formData. Could you please explain it little more

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212257/discussion-between-sajid-and-ilhank).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After comments, to fix the issue, you could use two updates:

1 - You don't need to use `JSON.stringify(formData)`, because when you use `.serialize()`, it generates the data like a `QueryString`, so which needs to be sent using the default `contentType`:`application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`, not as `JSON`.

2 -  Change little the `js` function, by replacing:

```
{
    project: JSON.stringify(formData)
}
```

By `formData`.
The js will be :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "#saveBtn", function () {

        var formData = $('#EditForm').serialize();

        $.post('@Url.Action("EditProject", "Home")', formData)
            .done(function (data) {
                if (data.success) {

                    alertify.success(data.message);

                } else {

                    alertify.error(data.message);
                }
            }).fail(function () {
                //alertify.error('Error while editing project');
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, @Sajid it worked. also using $.ajax({}) method worked.